# Mean Stack. Explain how client controller communicates with server controller through routes and how call the server methods

Tags: javascript, express, stack, mean

I am working on a mean stack application and having trouble sending requests to the Express/Node server to delete an element of an array in  Mongo.Here is my schema..

```
var DeckSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Deck name',
    trim: true
  },
  card: [{
    name: { 
      type: String, default: '', 
      trim: true,
      required: 'Please fill Card name'
    },...
```

---

Here is my client side route I have created

```
.state('decks.card', {
        url: '/:deckId/card/:cardId',
        templateUrl: 'modules/decks/client/views/view-card.client.view.html',
        controller: 'DecksController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          deckResolve: getDeck,
          cardResolve: getCard
        },...



function getDeck($stateParams, DecksService) {
    return DecksService.get({
      deckId: $stateParams.deckId
    }).$promise;
  }
  function getCard($stateParams, RemoveCardService) {
    return RemoveCardService.get({
      deckId: $stateParams.deckId,
      cardId: $stateParams.cardId
    }).$promise;
```

---

Here are the server side routes

```
app.route('/api/decks/:deckId/card/:cardId').all()
    .get(decks.read)
    .put(decks.update)
    .delete(decks.deleteCard);

  // Finish by binding the Deck middleware
  app.param('deckId', decks.deckByID);
  //app.param('cardId', decks.cardByID); This causes errors
```

---

server side controller

```
 exports.deleteCard = function(req, res) {

    res.send('In deleteCard');
    Deck.update(
        {'_id': req.body.deck_.id}, 
        { $pull: { "card" : { id: req.body.deck.card._id } } },
    false,
    true 
    );
      //decks.update( {id: req.params.deckId}, { $pullAll: {id: [req.params.cardId] } } )
    };
```

and middleware...

```
exports.cardByID = function(req, res, next, id){

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: 'Card is invalid'
    });
  }
      Deck.findById(id).populate('card','user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, deck) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else if (!deck) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: 'No Card with that identifier has been found'
      });
    }
    req.deck.card = deck.card;
    next();
  });
};
```

How do I call the deleteCard method in the client controller? My console is not printing the "In DeleteCard" message and I cant figure out what is wrong (From what I understand, The client controller uses the routes to determine which methods to call on the server side once the API is called. If I have not given sufficient information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `res.send` is not a `console.log`, res.send will just send something to the client. I don't remenber but I'm not sure that the rest of your function is execute (I mean after the res.send)

Answer (score 0):

You have to issue a "DELETE" request from your client. Seems like you are using Angular. So why not use $http?

```
$http({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: '/api/decks/111/card/222'
})
```

Your `DecksController` would have to have something like this

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('DecksController', ['$scope', '$http',  function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.deleteCard = function (deckId, cardId) {
            $http({
                method: "DELETE",
                url: '/api/decks/'+deckId+'/card/'+cardId
            })
            .then(function (resp) {
                console.log('response from server', resp)
            })
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: I have a service that uses ngresource to accomplish this in deck module, but I didnt include it in the originial post. Its for the api /api/decks/:deckId/card/:cardId. The client uses the service to communicate with the routes correct?

Comment: You are free to call the api from a controller or a service, angular allows that, but yes, it's best to have your business logic and state in the service, and that includes API calls.

Comment: angular.js:9893 DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/decks/card?id=57ef14e4058951ec0dbd24e9 400 (Bad Request) is the error im getting. The deckId isnt present, what does this indicate?

Comment: the url you called doesn't have a `deckId`, thus your server couldn't process the url because it's a `bad request` (that's what error 400 means)

Comment: test each part of your system separately. Test your backend first, using Postman, or pure curl from the CLI. Once you have your backend responding to all your requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), then proceed to debug your frontend

Comment: I appreciate the response , I got Postman a few days ago and worked with it a bit, I will try that approach

Comment: it's my pleasure to help. If I pointed you in the right direction, don't forget to accept the answer :)